# Google script - From: know if the response has been edited or is new

Tags: google-apps-script

I use the [onSubmit of a form](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events?hl=fr) that returns a FormResponse to send mail confirmation to users, and the link to update the response.

I can't figure out how to know the context of onSubmit(): Either if the response has been edited or is new.

There is no such function like isEdited() or isUpdated()

I tried getId() which always return a value.
I could also have compared the id with the url but [getUrl()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/service?hl=fr#getUrl%28%29) returns null.

My point is (not) sending a different email if the response is simply updated.

Answer (score 0):

You could manually read the responses sheet and see if its the last line. Will work except if responses are sent close in time (like another response arriving while the previous trigger executes)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the amount of expected responses can store the ID of each response, e.g., in [ScriptDb](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script-db) to determine whether to send the mail or not.

[ScriptProperties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/script-properties) **should not be used for these cases, I use it here only for demonstration purposes.**

```js
/* CODE FOR DEMONSTRATION PURPOSES */
function onFormSubmit(r) {
    var _key = r.response.getId();
    if (_key && !isEdited_(_key)) sendMail_();
}

function isEdited_(key) {
  var _isEdited = false;
  if (!ScriptProperties.getProperty(key))
      ScriptProperties.setProperty(key, 'FormResponse');
  else
      _isEdited = true;
  return _isEdited;
}
/* CODE FOR DEMONSTRATION PURPOSES */
```